# Changing input values during simulation

Tags: modeling, modelica, openmodelica

In openmodelica OMEdit, is there a way to resume a simulation after changing input values for a model? or is there a way to provide input vectors? I want to test a model and see its behaviour by changing inputs during simulation (without creating additional models that generate inputs).

Also what is the purpose of this bar shown below in the plotting perspective?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-simulate the model after changing the input values see [Re-simulating a Model](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omedit.html#re-simulating-a-model).

The simulation time bar is used with [Array Plot](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omedit.html#array-plot) and state machine debugging.

Comment: Is there a way to resume the simulation from the previous run without restarting?

Comment: You can use the [interactive simulation](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omedit.html#interactive-simulation) but note that this feature is experimental.